# LED Lighting Layout

Tags: lighting

I'm interested in using the 12 or 24 volt LED strip lighting that can be purchased online by cutting strips and applying them to the eight support ribs on an outdoor canopy. Can this be done in a "star" pattern using "T" connectors and feeding the star from the end of one of the star points?

To clarify further I am talking about a pattern with a center ring and eight lines radiating outward kind of like an asterisk "*". Please refer to the attached diagram.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: As long as you can find the proper "T" or "Y" connectors, this can be done.  Is there a certain problem you are worried about?  The installation of these strips is pretty easy and they normally just snap or push together.

Comment: Yes, I have ordered the correct "T" connectors for the five lead RGBW strip lights. My only concern is the layout. Looking at the diagram I just edited into the original question posting I think I may have to remove one part of the circle to avoid a short circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These strip lights are designed to be easy to install, so there's not a lot to worry about.

You can remove a *little* complexity by removing two of the T's and not making a full loop in the center.  If you start at the T on the "supply" strip as "1" and number the rest clockwise, the #1 T and the #8 T can be removed.

If you want everything to be symmetrical you can install just as your picture shows.  The wires will be connected to themselves, so there's not a short circuit situation here.

Comment: Thanks, I have revised the diagram to what I think you are referring to. Changing first and last "T" connectors to "L" connectors which can be omitted by directly connecting the connector cables to #2 and #7 "T" connectors.

Do I have this right?

One last question if you will  . . . would this application benefit by using 24 volt as opposed to 12 volt light strips?

Comment: I guess if the connecting cable is flat an L connector is good.  I was thinking you could just bend the cable, but I had a round "connector cable" in my mind for some reason...  Looks good!

Comment: Thanks again. I'll post pics as soon as I get around to putting this together.